# DOM not Populating in PhantomJS when Accessing Through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for a good many days now, but have not been having much luck.

The versions I am using are as follows:

-Java 8

-Selenium 3.4.0

-PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Have had the same results with PhantomJS 2.1.1)

-JUnit 4.12 (The code is getting called through JUnit.)

Everything is happening on Windows 10 for this run, but I have had similar issues on CentOS 7.

I am attempting to run Selenium with PhantomJS and am running into issues getting a page to become fully available.

Below is a code snippet (with a ton of System.outs for testing purposes) in which I run into problems:

> ```
>    methodDriver.manage().window().maximize();
>
>    System.out.println(methodDriver.getPageSource());
>
>    WebElement trackingInbox = methodDriver.findElement(By.id("inbox-widget-container-id"));
>
>   WebElement inboxBody = trackingInbox.findElement(By.xpath("div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody"));
>
>  >  List<WebElement> rows = inboxBody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
> ```

I get

> "errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'inbox-widget-container-id'"
>    at the line:
>   WebElement trackingInbox = methodDriver.findElement(By.id("inbox-widget-container-id"));

This makes some since because when I print the page source at the second line, these are the DOM contents:

```html
<body id="inboxBody" style="border:none; width:99%; align:center">
 <div id="inboxContent">
  <div class="mui-panel mui-panel-header">
   <p class="mui--text-subhead">Tracking Inbox</p>
  </div>
  <div id="inboxes_div">
   <div id="inboxes_control_section">
    <div id="inboxes_control_inboxGroup" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 5px;">
     <select id="inbox_group" name="inbox_group"></select>
    </div>
    <div id="inboxes_control_inbox" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
     <select id="inboxes" name="inboxes"></select>
    </div>
   </div>
   <p></p>
   <div id="inbox_content_div" style="padding-top: 5px;"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="inbox_content_totalRecords" value="">
 </div>
 <br>
</body>
```

If, however, I use either chrome or firefox (headed) I get the following:

```html
<body id="inboxBody" style="border: none; width: 957px;"><div id="inbox-widget-container-id" class="ui-resizable" style="width: 958px; margin-left: 1px; height: 500px;"><div class="grid-widget" style="width: 955px;"><div class="heading" style="background: linear-gradient(rgb(66, 139, 202), rgb(7, 105, 173)); border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom: 0px; width: 955px;"><table class="heading" style="width: 938px; table-layout: fixed;"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align: center; height: 35px; width: 90px;"><div class="btn-group no-border condensed"><span class="btn btn-primary btn-sm thin-padding no-border hover-effect sortable" data-sortable-event="click">Case�#�<i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc fa-fw fa-opaque"> . . .
     <div id="inboxContent" style="display: none;">
    <div class="mui-panel mui-panel-header">
     <p class="mui--text-subhead">Tracking Inbox</p>
    </div>
    <div id="inboxes_div">
          <div id="inboxes_control_section">
      <div id="inboxes_control_inboxGroup" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 5px;">
       <select id="inbox_group" name="inbox_group"><option value="inbox.group.case">Case</option><option value="group.InvestiagtionItems">Investigation Items</option></select>
      </div>
      <div id="inboxes_control_inbox" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
       <select id="inboxes" name="inboxes"><option value="inbox.cases">Assigned</option></select>
      </div>
     </div>
     <p></p>
     <div id="inbox_content_div" style="padding-top: 5px;"></div>
         </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="inbox_content_totalRecords" value="" />
   </div>
    <br />
 
</body>
```

Notice that the first line goes on for a very long time (I deliberately cut it short here). That line contains the elements I want to work with, but are not showing up in PhantomJS.

Above the “” element, there is a large “” element with a jquery script. I have heard suggestions that this script is not running in phantomjs and that it would populate the DOM if it did. So, maybe I need to find out how to get it to run in phantom, though I am having some trouble figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to wait for an element. Otherwise, the website doesn’t allow PhantomJS. Let’s try the wait first, see the example below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(methodDriver, 10);
WebElement trackingInbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("inbox-widget-container-id")));
```

Comment: Hmm. I'd have done well to have mentioned attempting that. That, of course, is the probably answer to something like this. As it happens, I gave wait another shot. Same results, unfortunately. It looks like the DOM just never gets any of the elements that should go in it.

Comment: I wonder. Would you know if there is particular types of content that PhantomJS can't touch? This website is something we developed in house, so we know there was nothing done to explicitly forbid phantom. Maybe just the technology used for the site.

Comment: @somexp12 If your website check User-Agent in HTTP header to avoid scraping, PhantomJS won’t work.

Comment: Would that be something set up in Tomcat or elsewhere? I have a partial ability to change the settings on the website, so this may be fixable, but not sure how such a thing is set up normally. I imagine a good many others might find such a thing useful because a lot of folks would have *some* control of the website they were testing.